# GWT AutoComplete Or Suggest Box

Tags: java, gwt, suggestbox

I am using suggest box for implementing autocomplete in GWT.
For retrieving data from entity i am using objectify and for mapping data to suggest box i have used MultiWordSuggestOracle.

On form load i am firing a query for retrieving data and passing it to MultiWordSuggestOracle. It is working fine.

For eg if i am loading customer data in suggestion it is working

But for eg if i have 5000 - 50000 customer records in my entity, so to retrieve all data and show it in suggestion could not be successful.

So is there any other technique for using autocomplete in gwt?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading allt he customer records in on form load, dynamically filter the data on the backend based on what the user types into the `SuggestBox`. You can do this by implementing a custom `SuggestOracle` (maybe extending the `MultiWordSuggestOracle`).

```
public class ServerSuggestOracle extends SuggestOracle{

    protected DataSource datasource;
    protected int startQueryLength;
    protected ArrayList<T> suggestions = new ArrayList<T>();
    protected boolean isMoreSuggestions = false;
    protected int previousQueryLength = 0;

    public ServerSuggestOracle(DataSource datasource,int startQueryLength) 
    {
        super();
        this.datasource = datasource;
        this.startQueryLength = startQueryLength;

    }

    @Override
    public void requestSuggestions(final Request request, final Callback callback) {
        // start the backend call only if the user types in more than startQueryLength characters.
        if (request.getQuery().length() < startQueryLength) 
            return;
        // if the user expands the search or a serach hasn't been carried out, call the backend. Otherwise filte the existing list
        if (isMoreSuggestions || previousQueryLength > request.getQuery().length() || suggestions.size() == 0) 
        {
            datasource.fetchDataFromBackend(request.getQuery(), new FetchDataFromBackendCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onFetchData(ArrayList<T> genes,Integer count,boolean isMore) {

                    suggestions.clear();
                    for (int i = 0;i<genes.size();i++) {
                        Suggestion suggestion = new Suggestion();
                        suggestions.add(suggestion);
                    }
                    SuggestOracle.Response response = new SuggestOracle.Response(suggestions);
                    isMoreSuggestions = isMore; 
                    if (count != null)
                        response.setMoreSuggestionsCount(count);
                    else
                        response.setMoreSuggestions(isMore);
                    previousQueryLength =  request.getQuery().length();
                    callback.onSuggestionsReady(request,response);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            super.requestSuggestions(request,cabllack);
        }
    }

}
```